# Checking whether a sequence $X_n$ satisfies the laws of large numbers

Tags: probability, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

**Weak Law of Large Numbers:**
let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of independent random variables with the same probability distribution, expected value $E(X_k) = m < \infty$ and $Var(X_k) = \sigma_k < \infty$. Then $\forall_{\epsilon > 0}$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P \big( \big|\frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{n} - m\big| > \epsilon \big) = 0. \tag{1}$$
**Strong Law of Large Numbers:**
let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of independent random variables with the same probability distribution, expected value $E(X_k) = m < \infty$. Then:
$$P \big(\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{X_1 + ... + X_n}{n} = m\big) = 1. \tag{2}$$

---

**My problem**

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables. We know that:

1. $P(X_n = \pm n) = 2^{-n},$
2. $P(X_n = 0) = 1 - 2^{-n + 1}.$

Our task is check whether the sequence $X_n$ satisfies $(1)$ or $(2)$.

I started to calculate the expected value of $E(X_n):$
$$E(X_n) = n2^{-n} + (-n)2^{-n} + 0(1 - 2^{-n + 1}) = 0.$$
Unfortunately I don't really know where to go from here. I would appreciate any hints or tips.

Comment: What are you trying to show?

Comment: @Titus I'm sorry. It was written only in the topic. Now I fixed that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n\geqslant 1}\Pr\left\{X_n\neq 0\right\}$ is convergent hence by the Borel-Cantelli lemma, there exists $\Omega'\subset \Omega$ of probability one such that for all $\omega\in \Omega'$, there is an integer $N\left(\omega\right)$ such that for all $n\geqslant N\left(\omega\right)$, $X_n\left(\omega\right)=0$.

Comment: It is because from the Borel-Cantelli lemma $\limsup \text{Pr} \{ X_n \neq 0 \} = 0$? How can I apply this result to the Laws of Large Numbers?

Comment: Yes for your first question. For the second only the first $N(\omega)$ terms may be non-zero hence $S_n(\omega)/n:=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j(\omega)/n=\sum_{j=1}^{N(\omega)}X_j(\omega)/n$.

Comment: I did some research on Borel-Cantelli lemma. I did the proofs and tried to understand it as best as I can. However I still don't see how can I get from the conclusion of the lemma to the laws of large numbers. Can I ask for a deeper answer? Thank you!

Comment: Once you have $S_n(\omega)/n:=\sum_{j=1}^nX_j(\omega)/n=\sum_{j=1}^{N(\omega)}X_j(\omega)/n$, we can derive that $S_n(\omega)/n\to 0$.